# First row as column names in C# Export to Excel File

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset, excel-interop

I've written a small application that takes my SQL query and outputs the data to an excel file and emails it to myself. Everything works wonderfully except that I am not getting the first row as column names. I imagine I'm missing a parameter somewhere that would do this or perhaps I need to manually hardcode that first line line of names in it? Here is my code:

```
namespace MaintenanceReportDBtoExcel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection cnn;
            string connectionString = null;
            string sql = null;
            string data = null;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;

            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            connectionString = @"data source=MFG-DB-DEV;Integrated Security=true;initial catalog=OLTP;";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cnn.Open();
            sql = @"SELECT MS.MaintCompletionDate, RF.ObjectType, RD.ResourceName, MRB.MaintenanceReqName, MS.NextDateDue,
                    CASE
                        WHEN

                            CASE MRB.MaintenanceReqName
                                WHEN 'Bi-Annual' THEN DATEADD(year, 2, MS.LastDateDue)
                                WHEN 'Annual' THEN DATEADD(year, 1, MS.LastDateDue)
                                WHEN 'Calibration - Annual' THEN DATEADD(year, 1, MS.LastDateDue)
                                WHEN 'Annual - ASY' THEN DATEADD(year, 1, MS.LastDateDue)
                                WHEN 'Semi-Annual' THEN DATEADD(month, 6, MS.LastDateDue)
                                WHEN 'Calibration - Semi-Annual' THEN DATEADD(month, 6, MS.LastDateDue)
                                WHEN 'Quarterly' THEN DATEADD(month, 3, MS.LastDateDue)
                                WHEN 'Calibration - Quarterly' THEN DATEADD(month, 3, MS.LastDateDue)
                                WHEN 'Quarterly - ASY' THEN DATEADD(month, 3, MS.LastDateDue)
                                WHEN 'Monthly' THEN DATEADD(month, 1, MS.LastDateDue)
                                WHEN 'Calibration - Weekly' THEN DATEADD(week, 1, MS.LastDateDue)
                                WHEN 'Weekly - ASY' THEN DATEADD(week, 1, MS.LastDateDue)
                                WHEN 'Semi-Annual - ASY' THEN DATEADD(month, 6, MS.LastDateDue)
                                WHEN 'Monthly - ASY' THEN DATEADD(month, 1, MS.LastDateDue)
                                WHEN 'Bi-Annual - ASY' THEN DATEADD(year, 2, MS.LastDateDue)
                                WHEN 'Weekly' THEN DATEADD(week, 1, MS.LastDateDue)
                                END < GETDATE() THEN 'PAST DUE'

                        WHEN MS.LastDateDue IS NULL AND MS.NextDateDue < GETDATE() THEN 'PAST DUE'

                        WHEN MS.LastDateDue IS NULL AND MS.NextDateDue > GETDATE() THEN 'READY'

                        WHEN MS.LastDateDue IS NULL AND MS.NextDateDue IS NULL THEN 'N/A'

                        ELSE 'READY'
                    END AS MaintenanceStatus
                    FROM CamstarSch.ResourceDef RD
                    INNER JOIN CamstarSch.MaintenanceStatus MS ON RD.ResourceId = MS.ResourceId
                    INNER JOIN CamstarSch.ResourceFamily RF ON RF.ResourceFamilyId = RD.ResourceFamilyId
                    INNER JOIN CamstarSch.AssignedMaintReq AMR ON AMR.AssignedMaintReqId = MS.AssignedMaintReqId
                    INNER JOIN CamstarSch.MaintenanceReq MR ON AMR.MaintenanceReqId = MR.MaintenanceReqId
                    INNER JOIN CamstarSch.MaintenanceReqBase MRB ON MRB.MaintenanceReqBaseId = MR.MaintenanceReqBaseId
                    ORDER BY NextDateDue DESC; ";
            SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dscmd.Fill(ds);

            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = data;
                }
            }

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\mbelmer\Desktop\Helpful Files\Test files\MaintenanceReport.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
            GC.Collect();

            MailHelper.SendMail(new string[] { "mbelmer@rocelec.com" }, $"Maintenance Report {DateTime.Today}", $"Maintenance Report for {DateTime.Today}", new string[] { @"C:\Users\mbelmer\Desktop\Helpful Files\Test files\MaintenanceReport.xls" });
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            File.Delete(@"C:\Users\mbelmer\Desktop\Helpful Files\Test files\MaintenanceReport.xls");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to loop over the Columns collection of the datatable extracting the ColumnName property and add it to your excel file before starting the loop over the datatable rows

Comment: Need to set HDR option in connection string.  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: @jdweng Yes that sounds exactly what I'm looking for but that's not the SqlConnection string right? What would this look like in code? I apologize I'm still very new to exporting database data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try replace this:

```
for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = data;
            }
        }
```

On this:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            data = ds.Tables[0].Columns[j].ColumnName;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, j + 1] = data;
        }

for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This worked except that it doesn't grab the Column name from the last column that isn't actually a column in the database but a column created by the query that is based off criteria in the table. I SHOULD be okay but is there a way around that you think?